# Is GEE a good replacement for ANCOVA to analyze change from baseline on 8-points Likert item?

Tags: likert, ancova, generalized-estimating-equations, pre-post-comparison

I was asked to analyze adjusted change from baseline. The variable of interest is a customer answer reported on 8-point Likert scale, but constructed from numbers 0 - 8, rather than labels ("weak", "moderate", "strong" etc). ANCOVA on changes adjusted for baseline immediately assumes reporting arithmetic means. Likert, meaning ordinal scale, breaks all the assumptions on the linear model, including normality of residuals. Even if the normality is about the change. Change inferred from such data is not continuous, even if the histogram might resemble bell curve. I checked the distribution of changes (not raw data) and got almost uniform distribution, and in another sub-set - moderately right skewed one. Running a linear model is technically possible, but not valid. I have heard that GEE relaxes most of the parametric assumptions, which are not mandatory, however it improves the asymptotic properties. And, what is more important, it supports repeated observations and reports still arithmetic means, if the conditional distribution is set to Gaussian. Of course this doesn't hold in my case, but since they asked me to report arithmetic mean on skewed data - I won't argue. Just wanted to make sure the choice on GEE is reasonable (over the mixed models, which require normality of random effects and residuals).